# Entity Framework 6: Add to child collections

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 code first. I have an parent entity (Expense) which has collection of child entity (Tag). Entities are

```
 public class Expense : Entity
{
    //public Expense()
    //{
    //    this.Tags = new HashSet<Tag>();
    //}
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    //public long TagId { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public long ByUserId { get; set; }
    public User ByUser { get; set; }

    public long? ForUserId { get; set; }
    public User ForUser { get; set; }

    public DateTime ExpenseDate { get; set; }
}

 public class Tag : Entity
{
    public Tag()
    {
        this.Expenses = new HashSet<Expense>();
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }

    public long OrganizationId { get; set; }

    public Organization Organization { get; set; }
}
```

Configured as

```
 public ExpenseConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasRequired(x => x.ByUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ByUserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasOptional(x => x.ForUser)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.ForUserId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        this.HasMany(x => x.Tags)
            .WithMany(t => t.Expenses)
            .Map(et => { 
                et.MapLeftKey("ExpenseId");
                et.MapRightKey("TagId");
                et.ToTable("tblExpenseTags");
            });
    }

 public TagConfiguration()
    {
        this.HasRequired(x => x.Organization)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.OrganizationId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
```

The way I am saving entity

```
var tags = new List<Tag>();
        foreach (var item in expense.Tags)
        {
            var tag = _TagHandler.Get().Where(x => x.Id == item.Id).FirstOrDefault();
            tags.Add(tag);
        }

        entity.Tags.Clear();
        foreach (var item in tags)
        {
            expense.Tags.Add(item);
        }

if (expense.Id == 0)
        {
            entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            entity.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            updated = EntityRepository.Add(entity);
        }
        else
        {
            expense.UpdatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            updated = EntityRepository.Update(entity);
        }
        UnitOfWork.Commit();
```

When i Create Expense I add multiple tags to it and it save successfully in tblExpenseTags, but the problem is when I add new tags to Expense they are not saving into tblExpenseTags table. I used sql profiler to see what calls are going to SQL database and I don't see any insert call at the time of update expense.

Please let me know what wrong am I doing ?

Comment: What you do is in fact trying to modify the existing Tags in `expense.Tags` by obtaining the corresponding Tag instances (having the same Id with all tags in `expense.Tags`), then clear the `expense.Tags` and add each new to `expense.Tags`. That means if `expense.Tags` has no item, you have no tags added. If it has some item then `expense.Tags` will have just the same Tags having the same Id but maybe with some modified properties. It depends on how `_TagHandler.Get()` resolving the tags. I doubt it may just load all Tags from db. So in fact there is no change in Tags at all.

Comment: Yes, it loads all the tags. The flow is
expense entity has all tags (before loading from db tags has only ids) new and old. When i Load tags i match tag ids and attach tag object to expense. so it attaches old tags objects and new tag objects. Then I save it. I hope it clarifies your doubt ?

Comment: what I said is exactly what you does. There won't be no new and old in your final `Tags`. There are just new ones (after clearing all) but as I said, all those new ones having the `Id` matching all the cleared ones (each one by each one). So technically it is like removing all and ***re-add*** all. The only thing here is the new ones may have some properties modified (depending on the `_TagHandler.Get()`). If there is not any modified, then you will see no change in Tags (there is nothing added or removed as well as modified).

Comment: So, how do you suggest i should add or remove tags to a expense ?